# No significant variable but AIC very low and accurancy equal to 100 %?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, interpretation, aic

How should I judge and interpret the result of my logistic model knowing that I get:

```
> summary(model2)

Call:
glm(formula = OUTCOME ~ . - 1, family = binomial, data = train)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-1.140e-04  -2.100e-08   2.100e-08   2.100e-08   8.318e-05  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
DataCRMSanoflore.Year_Sales             -1.961e-01  8.609e+03   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.HOURS_INSCR             1.221e-02  3.212e+02   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Month_Sales             2.819e-02  9.469e+02   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Date_Sales             -1.531e-02  2.073e+02   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.HOURS_INSCR.1                  NA         NA      NA       NA
DataCRMSanoflore.Year_Creation_Sales    -5.552e+01  3.001e+07   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Month_Creation_Sales    2.431e-01  1.116e+04   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Day_Creation_Sales      5.216e-02  5.201e+02   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Year_Validation_Sales   5.504e+01  3.001e+07   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Month_Validation_Sales -2.692e-01  1.115e+04   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Day_Validation_Sales   -3.783e-02  4.907e+02   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.AGE_CUSTUMER            4.375e-04  1.151e+02   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.MEAN_PURCHASE          -9.266e-03  7.285e+01   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.NUMBER_GIFTS            1.238e+00  5.554e+03   0.000    1.000
TYPE_PEAUGrasse                         -2.217e+02  2.191e+04  -0.010    0.992
TYPE_PEAUMixte                          -2.218e+02  2.196e+04  -0.010    0.992
TYPE_PEAUNormale                        -2.214e+02  2.204e+04  -0.010    0.992
TYPE_PEAUSèche                          -2.219e+02  2.191e+04  -0.010    0.992
SENSIBILITEFréquente                     1.346e+00  5.825e+03   0.000    1.000
SENSIBILITEOccasionnelle                 8.420e-01  5.351e+03   0.000    1.000
IMPERFECTIONSOccasionnelle               5.786e-01  3.457e+03   0.000    1.000
IMPERFECTIONSRares                       1.748e+00  6.313e+03   0.000    1.000
BRILLANCEPartout                        -7.664e-02  7.964e+03   0.000    1.000
BRILLANCEZone T                          8.685e-02  4.516e+03   0.000    1.000
GRAIN_PEAUFin                            4.250e-01  5.543e+03   0.000    1.000
GRAIN_PEAUMoyen                         -2.279e-01  3.494e+03   0.000    1.000
RIDES_VISAGETrès visibles               -5.461e-01  6.655e+03   0.000    1.000
RIDES_VISAGEVisibles                    -1.543e-01  3.337e+03   0.000    1.000
ALLERGIESOui                            -4.460e-01  6.228e+03   0.000    1.000
MAINSNormales                            8.189e-01  6.164e+03   0.000    1.000
MAINSSèches                              3.941e-01  6.464e+03   0.000    1.000
PEAU_CORPSSèche                         -1.786e-02  3.255e+03   0.000    1.000
PEAU_CORPSTrès sèche                     1.027e-02  4.649e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLEPas du tout        4.255e-02  9.912e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLEUn peu             3.198e-01  3.596e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_ORIGINE_GEOPas du tout          -4.795e-01  7.632e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_ORIGINE_GEOUn peu                3.815e-02  3.373e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_VACANCESÀ la montagne            1.207e-01  3.034e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_VACANCESEn ville                 8.539e-01  7.329e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENTPas du tout        -1.110e+00  2.059e+04   0.000    1.000
INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENTUn peu             -2.278e-01  3.990e+03   0.000    1.000
INTERET_COMPOSITIONPas du tout           6.032e-02  2.345e+04   0.000    1.000
INTERET_COMPOSITIONUn peu                2.662e-01  3.736e+03   0.000    1.000
DataCRMSanoflore.Nb_achats               4.009e+01  2.408e+03   0.017    0.987

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.7329e+03  on 1250  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5.5683e-07  on 1207  degrees of freedom
AIC: 86

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Just look to the AIC.

As other results, we see that:

```
> table_mat <-table(test$OUTCOME, predictions > 0.5)
> table_mat

    FALSE TRUE
  0   157    0
  1     0  260
> accuracy_Test <- sum(diag(table_mat)) / sum(table_mat)
> accuracy_Test
[1] 1
```

the occuracy is 100% which is very weird in this case odf study!

how should I interpret please?